# Does 4nec2 allow SY variables/formulas in integer fields?

Tags: antenna-modeling

I've looked at the various guides I found on the 'web, and I cannot find a single example of a 4nec2 deck that has a variable or formula in one of the integer fields. But at the same time, none of those documents say you *can't* put one there.

I'm on the mac trying to make a parser that can also handle 4nec2, so I can't test this myself. Can someone with a copy of 4nec2 give this a try?

Comment: As noted in the subject and body, this question refers to **4nec2**, a popular NEC-based GUI program that supports variable types with the SY card.